# Print letters in specific pattern in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have the follwing string and I split it:

```
>>> st = '%2g%k%3p'
>>> l = filter(None, st.split('%'))
>>> print l
['2g', 'k', '3p']
```

Now I want to print the g letter two times, the k letter one time and the p letter three times:

```
ggkppp
```

How is it possible?

Comment: Is this coming from html code?

Comment: Will the number before the letter ever be more than a single digit? Will the number ever be zero?

Comment: @Irano No this isnt ..

Comment: @PM Yes it may be mor than one digit...

Comment: You need a more formal/flushed out specification of the input language. What exactly does the `%` mean, what values for the number are valid, and what values for the "string to print" are valid? For example, what would `%234` mean? Would it mean "print `34` twice," or is it invalid since no letter follows, or something else? What about `%55a5`? Print `a5` fifty five times, maybe, or print `5a5` five times, or print `5` five times and then print `a5`? There are a ton of cases you haven't specified here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### LATE FOR THE SHOW BUT READY TO GO

Another way, is to define your function which converts nC into CCCC...C (ntimes), then pass it to a `map` to apply it on every element of the list `l` coming from the `split` over `%`, the finally `join` them all, as follows:

```
>>> def f(s):
        x = 0
        if s:
            if len(s) == 1:
                out = s
            else:
                for i in s:
                    if i.isdigit():
                        x = x*10 + int(i)
                out = x*s[-1]

        else:
            out = ''
        return out

>>> st
'%4g%10k%p'
>>> ''.join(map(f, st.split('%')))
'ggggkkkkkkkkkkp'
>>> st = '%2g%k%3p'
>>> ''.join(map(f, st.split('%')))
'ggkppp'
```

Or if you want to put all of these into one single function definition:

```
>>> def f(s):
        out = ''
        if s:
            l = filter(None, s.split('%'))
            for item in l:
                x = 0
                    if len(item) == 1:
                        repl = item
                    else:
                        for c in item:
                            if c.isdigit():
                                x = x*10 + int(c)
                        repl = x*item[-1]
                    out += repl

        return out

>>> st
'%2g%k%3p'
>>> f(st)
'ggkppp'
>>> 
>>> st = '%4g%10k%p'
>>> 
>>> f(st)
'ggggkkkkkkkkkkp'
>>> st = '%4g%101k%2p'
>>> f(st)
'ggggkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkpp'
>>> len(f(st))
107
```

**EDIT :**

In case of the presence of `_` where the OP does not want this character to be repeated, then the best way in my opinion is to go with [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#re.sub), it will make things easier, this way:

```
>>> def f(s):
        pat = re.compile(r'%(\d*)([a-zA-Z]+)')
        out = pat.sub(lambda m:int(m.group(1))*m.group(2) if m.group(1) else m.group(2), s)
        return out

>>> st = '%4g_%12k%p__%m'
>>> f(st)
'gggg_kkkkkkkkkkkkp__m'
```

Comment: @MLSC...what's your expected output in this case? `gg_kkkkkkkkkkkkkppp` ?

Comment: Pardon I meant: `But if I say st = %2g_%12k%3p result is not `gg_kkkkkkkkkkkkkppp` or even when `st = %2g___%12k%3p` result must be `gg___kkkkkkkkkkkkkppp`

Comment: @MLSC .. no pblm .. :)

Answer (score 15):

You could use `generator` with `isdigit()` to check wheter your first symbol is digit or not and then return following string with appropriate count. Then you could use `join` to get your output:

```
''.join(i[1:]*int(i[0]) if i[0].isdigit() else i for i in l)
```

Demonstration:

```
In [70]: [i[1:]*int(i[0]) if i[0].isdigit() else i for i in l ]
Out[70]: ['gg', 'k', 'ppp']

In [71]: ''.join(i[1:]*int(i[0]) if i[0].isdigit() else i for i in l)
Out[71]: 'ggkppp'
```

**EDIT**

Using `re` module when first number is with several digits:

```
''.join(re.search('(\d+)(\w+)', i).group(2)*int(re.search('(\d+)(\w+)', i).group(1)) if re.search('(\d+)(\w+)', i) else i for i in l)
```

Example:

```
In [144]: l = ['12g', '2kd', 'h', '3p']

In [145]: ''.join(re.search('(\d+)(\w+)', i).group(2)*int(re.search('(\d+)(\w+)', i).group(1)) if re.search('(\d+)(\w+)', i) else i for i in l)
Out[145]: 'ggggggggggggkdkdhppp'
```

**EDIT2**

For your input like:

```
st = '%2g_%3k%3p'
```

You could replace `_` with empty string and then add `_` to the end if the work from list endswith the `_` symbol:

```
st = '%2g_%3k%3p'
l = list(filter(None, st.split('%')))
''.join((re.search('(\d+)(\w+)', i).group(2)*int(re.search('(\d+)(\w+)', i).group(1))).replace("_", "") + '_' * i.endswith('_') if re.search('(\d+)(\w+)', i) else i for i in l)
```

Output:

```
'gg_kkkppp'
```

**EDIT3**

Solution without `re` module but with usual loops working for 2 digits. You could define functions:

```
def add_str(ind, st):
    if not st.endswith('_'):
        return st[ind:] * int(st[:ind])
    else:
        return st[ind:-1] * int(st[:ind]) + '_'

def collect(l):
    final_str = ''
    for i in l:
        if i[0].isdigit():
            if i[1].isdigit():
                final_str += add_str(2, i)
            else:
                final_str += add_str(1, i)
        else:
            final_str += i
    return final_str
```

And then use them as:

```
l = ['12g_', '3k', '3p']

print(collect(l))
gggggggggggg_kkkppp
```

Comment: What happens when there are more than 9 of a letter?

Comment: `''.join(i[1:]*int(i[0]) if i[0].isdigit() else i for i in ['12g', 'k', '3p'])` = `'2gkppp'`

Comment: @Anton. imagin: `st = '%2g_%3k%3p'` so the result is:`'g_g_kkkppp'` but I want this result: `'gg_kkkppp'`

Comment: @MLSC do you need that behavior only for `_` sign?

Comment: @Anton Yes I need. All other signs are junctions

Comment: @Anton Isn't solution without re module? like your first solution `''.join(i[1:]*int(i[0]) if i[0].isdigit() else i for i in l)`?

Comment: I found it: `''.join(i[1]*int(i[0])+i[2:] if i[0].isdigit() else i for i in l)`. How about patterns like `%12g_%3k%3p`?  before g I have 12. more than 9.

Comment: @MLSC what is the most high number do you have? Are the only with 2 digits or could be more?

Comment: @Anton. It can be more yes... Thank you

Comment: @MLSC so without `re` module for these cases it's hard to separate your strings for number and string itself. Or it'll be very specific solution.

Comment: @Anton Even for two digits? up tp 99?

Comment: @MLSC try edited version. You could extend it to what you like

Answer (score 13):

One-liner Regex way:

```
>>> import re
>>> st = '%2g%k%3p'
>>> re.sub(r'%|(\d*)(\w+)', lambda m: int(m.group(1))*m.group(2) if m.group(1) else m.group(2), st)
'ggkppp'
```

`%|(\d*)(\w+)` regex matches all `%` and captures zero or moredigit present before any word character into one group and the following word characters into another group. On replacement all the matched chars should be replaced with the value given in the replacement part. So this should loose `%` character.

or

```
>>> re.sub(r'%(\d*)(\w+)', lambda m: int(m.group(1))*m.group(2) if m.group(1) else m.group(2), st)
'ggkppp'
```

Comment: can u explain why you used `\b` ?...because I think it's not necessary?

Comment: Test: `re.sub(r'%(\d*)(\w*)', '-RE-',st)` ---> `'-RE--RE--RE-'`

Comment: For lowercase letters only `r'%(\d*)([a-z]+)'`

Answer (score 11):

Assumes you are always printing single letter, but preceding number may be longer than single digit in base 10.

```
seq = ['2g', 'k', '3p']
result = ''.join(int(s[:-1] or 1) * s[-1] for s in seq)
assert result == "ggkppp"
```

Comment: Or as a one-liner: `result = ''.join([int(s[:-1] or 1) * s[-1] for s in st.split('%') if s])`. You _can_ give `.join` a generator expression but it's actually more efficient to give it a list comp. `.join` has to parse its input twice: the 1st pass determines the size of the output string, the 2nd pass builds the output. So if you give `.join` a gen exp it has to run the generator and build a list from it before it can start doing the actual joining.

Answer (score 4):

Loop the list, check first entry for number, and then append the second digit onwards:

```
string=''
l = ['2g', 'k', '3p']
for entry in l:
    if len(entry) ==1:
        string += (entry)
    else:
        number = int(entry[0])
        for i in range(number):
            string += (entry[1:])
```

Comment: `string` isn't a great variable name since it's the name of a standard Python module. Also, this answer won't work properly if a number has more than 1 digit.