# Split python list values

Tags: python, list, split

Imagin I have three lists like:

```
l = ['2g_', '3k', '3p']
p = ['3f', '2y_', '4k', 'p']
s = ['12g', 'k_', '3p']
```

So:

```
>>> ''.join(i[1]*int(i[0])+i[2:] if i[0].isdigit() else i for i in l)
'gg_kkkppp'
>>> ''.join(i[1]*int(i[0])+i[2:] if i[0].isdigit() else i for i in p)
'fffyy_kkkkp'
>>> ''.join(i[1]*int(i[0])+i[2:] if i[0].isdigit() else i for i in s)
'2gk_ppp'
```

But what in list s:
`2gk_ppp` must be `ggggggggggggk_ppp`

Comment: The problem is that you are not fetching the `12`, but only the first digit of it. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to capture two digits and print in number of them. for example 12g must print g 12 times... like other patterns in l and p lists

Comment: It doesn't wok in digits more than 9... I want increase it till 99

Comment: @MLSC just replace `\w+` in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35266372/3297613) answer to `[a-z]`

Comment: Have a look at regular expressions. "\d+" will match one or more digits (as string, you still have to convert them to a number).

Comment: Thank you.. I am not really keen on `re` ...

Comment: @Raj this is the error:`TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Comment: @Jasper Alsopart EDIT3 in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35266225/print-letters-in-specific-pattern-in-python/35266290#35266290 is good but not working properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension / generator expression with regular expressions.

```
def join(lst):
    return ''.join((int(n or 1) * c + r 
                    for (n, c, r) 
                    in (re.search(r"(\d*)(\w)(.*)", x).groups() for x in lst)))
```

First, use `re.search` with `(\d*)(\w)(.*)` to get the (optional) number, the character, and the (optional) rest for each string.

```
[re.search(r"(\d*)(\w)(.*)", x).groups() for x in lst]
```

For your second example, this gives `[('3', 'f', ''), ('2', 'y', '_'), ('4', 'k', ''), ('', 'p', '')]`. Now, in the outer generator, you can use `or` to provide a ["default-value"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) in case the number is `''` (or use a ternary expression if you prefer: `int(n) if n else 1`):

```
[int(n or '1') * c + r 
 for (n, c, r) 
 in (re.search(r"(\d*)(\w)(.*)", x).groups() for x in lst)]
```

This gives `['fff', 'yy_', 'kkkk', 'p']`. Finally, join to get `fffyy_kkkkp`.

Answer (score 0):

This variant is a little bit more imperative and simple to follow:

```
import re as regex

def process_template(template):
    result = regex.match('(\d*)(.)(.*)', template)
    if (result.group(1)):
        return int(result.group(1)) * result.group(2) + result.group(3)
    else:
        return result.group(2) + result.group(3)

''.join([process_template(template) for template in ['3f', '2y_', '4k', 'p']])
```